# Issues with Property Binding Order and converting datetimes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, deserialization, model-binding

I am using a C# Web API and I have a one class as below and it has below defined properties. This same class has been used in my Get/Post User info call. Basically when we storing the value in database we store datetime field in form of UTC format and when we retrieve it from database we will represent the value in form of User’s specific Timezone.

```
    public class UserInfo
    {
        private string _userHashId;

        public string UserHashId
        {
          get
          {
            return _userHashId;
          }
          set
          {
            // This property has been set after set the value of "RegistrationDate"
            _userHashId = value;
          }
        }

        public string TimeZone { get; set; }

        public string _registrationDate;

        public string RegistrationDate
        {
          get
          {
            return _registrationDate;
          }
          set
          {
            _registrationDate = value;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TimeZone))
            {
              // When this property's set method called "UserHashId" value is not available
              // and because of that TimeZone data is not available
              TimeZone = Helper.FindTimeZoneByUserHashId(UserHashId);
            }

            // User Timezone to UTC Timezone
            _registrationDateUTC = _registrationDate.ToUtcTimeZone(TimeZone);
          }
        }

        public DateTime _registrationDateUTC;

        public DateTime RegistrationDateUTC
        {
          get
          {
            return _registrationDateUTC;
          }
          set
          {
            _registrationDateUTC = value;

            // UTC Timezone to User Timezone
            _registrationDate = _registrationDateUTC.ToUserTimezone(TimeZone);
          }
        }
    }
```

In Get API call, user information displays properly with correct timezone information. However, when the user makes a Post request, datetime conversion is not working as expected because I have to find out the Timezone information based on UserHashId before converting actual time to UTC time, and I am not getting “UserHashId” value in “RegistrationDate”’s set block because it’s still not set.

Comment: There is no guarantee of the order, but generally its in the order of the form controls in your form. The only way to guarantee the order would be to create your own custom ModelBinder.

Comment: Having said that, it should not be necessary, because what you should be doing is using a view model in your view and then mapping to your data model, in which case, both your view model and data model only need simple `{ get; set; }` properties